# Why use square bracket for Symbol.iterator?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am new in TypeScript and stumbled over this piece of code:

```
let numbers = {
  *[Symbol.iterator]() {
    for (let i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
      yield i;
    }
  },
};
```

I wonder why the square brackets around Symbol.iterator are needed.

Comment: The square brackets allow an arbitrary expression to be evaluated. The result of that evaluation will be used as the property key. Keys can be either strings or Symbol instances, so in this case what you end up with is a property whose "name" is the system "iterator" Symbol instance.

Comment: Thank you. But why not just omit the square brackets?

Comment: Because it would be a syntax error.

Comment: @Pointy what do you mean "by _system_ "iterator" Symbol instance"?  Symbol.iterator is not an instance, it's a Symbol. That is also the static property of the _incomplete_ constructor "Symbol"

Comment: @ShahzadRahim every individual Symbol created is an instance of the Symbol type. Yes, you cannot use `new Symbol()`, but that doesn't mean that individual Symbols are not instances.